# Is it better to update an associated record through the parent or by itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Imagine we have an `Article` and a `Comment` model. We setup our routes like:

```
# routes.rb
resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end
```

Now, we can destroy a `comment` via the `CommentController`, but there are a number of approaches that I've seen been implemented.

```
# method 1
def destroy
  Comment.where(article_id: params[:article_id]).find(params[:id]).destroy
end

# method 2
def destroy
  Comment.find(params[:id]).destroy
end

# method 3
def destroy
  article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  comment = article.comments.find(params[:id])
  comment.destroy
end
```

**Which is better and why?**

I've seen in old [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources?autoplay=true) episodes and blogs that we should do the former for "security" reasons or because it is better to ensure that `comments` can only be found within their respective `article`, but why is that better? I haven't been able to find anything that goes too deep into the answer.

Comment: It depends on the use case. Overly nesting routes can be seen as a code smell and that security motivation seems dubious at best. It sound like something that should be handled be the authorization layer. Non-nested routes and controllers are less complex and avoid the need of having to pass around a second param.

Comment: definitely not the method 2. Unless you double-check if the user has access to that destroy action for that comment, he could simply modify the HTML, replace the id of the comment and destroy a Comment from somebody else. Usually, the third method is best, combined with a before_action which set the `@article` variable for all actions of that CommentsController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are working with nested data in this way, it's better to scope your model lookup under the parent to avoid people iterating through ids in a simplistic way. You generally want to discourage that, and it will protect you against more serious security problems if it's a habit.

For instance, say you have some sort of visibility permission on Article. With method 2, it is possible to use an `article_id` that you are allowed to see to access Comments that you aren't.

Methods 1 & 3 are ostensibly doing the same thing, but I would prefer 1 because it uses fewer trips to the DB.